# How to make the property change listener fire in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to update the user location on a map. So I've defined my LocationListener as follows :

```
public class UserLocationListener implements LocationListener {

  @Override
  public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
    User.getInstance().actualLocation.set(location);

  }

  @Override
  public void providerStateChanged(int newState) {

 }

}
```

The `actualLocation` is a Property defined following [CN1 guide on Properties](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties.html).

Within the simulator if I move user location with the location simulator then locationUpdated is fired.

Now in my MainForm class constructor if I add :

```
User.getInstance().actualLocation.addChangeListener((p) -> {
        System.err.println("User location has changed");
        // Update user location on the map
}
```

It is never fired although the map is shown with a marker (see `myMap.addMarker(...)`).

So my question is : why is this change listener not fired and where should I put it to make all work ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: Can you verify that the value of `actualLocation` is set? By calling `System.println(User.getInstance().actualLocation.get())` in your `locationUpdated`.

Comment: Hi Diamond thanks for your suggestion. Indeed it evolves along with `location` I checked it. But then the changeListener does not trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location code reuses the same location object instance and just changes the values within. The `set(T)` method in property only fires a change event if the new value `!=` the old value:

```
public K set(T value) {
    if(this.value != value) { 
        this.value = value;
        firePropertyChanged();
    }
    if(parent == null) {
        // allows properties to work even if they aren't registered in the index
        return null;
    }
    return (K)parent.parent;
}
```

So as a workaround you can use something like this:

```
public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
  Location l = new Location();
  l.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
  ... // etc. sucks that we don't have new Location(location)
  User.getInstance().actualLocation.set(l);
}
```

I'm not sure if it's wrong that we need that.

Comment: Thanks Shai! To make it trigger I first `set(new Location())` and then `set(location)`. This avoids having to copy all fields of `location` into `l`. I agree `Location(location)` would be handy! In my opinion for this case using `!this.value.equals(value)` instead of `this.value != value` would make sense to firePropertyChanged. So maybe `set(T value, boolean forceObjectEqualityCheck)` would help.

Comment: That would cause the event to fire twice and might cause a "bounce" effect.  Since we are changing the underlying object an equals call would still return true.

Comment: Yes I knew for the event fired twice so I ended up setting it first to `null` and then to `location`. In the `propertyChangedListener` I check if `actualLocation.get()` is `!=` from `null` before updating the UI. You wrote "the code reuses the same location object" so you are not changing the underlying object are you ?

Comment: Yes. Location can be fired a lot from the native implementation so we try to minimize allocations.